# Is it idiomatic to create an empty array and then fill it with an iterator?

Tags: ruby

Say that I want an array called `people` built from a database query. I would normally write

```
people = Array.new
db.execute("select name from people") {|person| people << person}
```

Works fine, but I was wondering if there's a way to do that in one line, creating an array if it doesn't already exist and then filling it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not idiomatic. Use `to_a`:

`people = db.execute("select name from people").to_a`